# hyperref Form spanning multiple markdown sections?

Tags: hyperref, pandoc, markdown

`begin{Form}` and `end{Form}` currently works in `markdown` if there is no markdown syntax in-between:

```
\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=Title, width=0.87\textwidth, bordercolor=black, value = {Some default value}]{Title:}
\end{Form}
```

But as long as I move `end{Form}` down to the end of the markdown document in order to cover multiple form fields, it stops working:

```
---
title: "Test Latex Form"
geometry: "left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{hyperref}
    - \usepackage{datetime}
    - \usepackage{xcolor}   
---

# Overview

\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=Title, width=0.87\textwidth, bordercolor=black, value = {Some default value}]{Title:}


## A heading:
* Some markdown syntax here*

\TextField[name=field1, width=\hsize, bordercolor=black, value = {}]{}

## Another heading:
*And form field below*

\TextField[name=field2, width=\hsize, bordercolor=black, value = {}]{}

\end{Form}
```

Pandoc command:

```
pandoc --number-section -o TestLatexForm.pdf TestLatexForm.md -f markdown+raw_tex
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: better ask on the pandoc mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

I got the working solution over here: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5209

Basically I have to use literal `latex` blocks to specify form:

````
 ---
 title: "Test Latex Form"
 geometry: "left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
 output: pdf_document
 header-includes:
     - \usepackage{hyperref}
     - \usepackage{datetime}
     - \usepackage{xcolor}
 ---
 # Overview

  ```{=latex}
 \begin{Form}
 ```

 \TextField[name=Title, width=0.87\textwidth, bordercolor=black, value = {Some default value}]{Title:}

 ## A heading:
 * Some markdown syntax here*

 \TextField[name=field1, width=\hsize, bordercolor=black, value = {}]{}

 ## Another heading:
 *And form field below*

 \TextField[name=field2, width=\hsize, bordercolor=black, value = {}]{}

 ```{=latex}
 \end{Form}
  ```
````